# making slideToggle selective when it unhides

Tags: html, jquery

I have been struggling with nextUntil and slideToggle to make collapsible sections. I know I could do this with  wrappers, but I really do not want to - since I would like to be able to add this to existing files without editing. My aim is to manage a file that has (e.g.)

```
<h1>Heading</h1><p>some stuff></p>
   <h2>heading</h2><p>blah....</p>
   <h2>heading</h2><p>blah....</p>    
   <h2>heading</h2><p>blah....</p>
<h1>Heading</h1><p>some stuff></p><p>more stuff</p>
   <h2>heading</h2><p>blah....</p>
   <h2>heading</h2><p>blah....</p>    
   <h2>heading</h2><p>blah....</p>
```

And be able to expand/collapse the stuff between h1 headings by clicking on the relevant heading, but only to show 'some stuff' and the h2 headings when the h1 heading is clicked, leavin gthe stuff below the h2 headings collapsed until you click on the h2 headings.

If it is only one level, I can do it fine

```
function collapsible(tag)
{
    $(tagname).nextUntil(tag).hide(); //hide everyting between one <tag> and the next
    $(tag).click(function(){    
        $(this).nextUntil(tag).slideToggle(500);
        });//handler to toggle visibility of the content between this <tag> and the next
}
```

But I can find now way to reliably ensure everything under the h2 headings remains hidden until asked for. Maybe someone has an idea. I have searched all the places I can think of, but not found anything like a solution to this. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: create a fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
$(function () {
    $('h2,p').hide();
});    

test = function (me) {
    $(me).nextUntil('h2').slideToggle(500);
    $(me).nextUntil('h1').filter('h2').slideToggle(500).off('click').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle(500);
    });
}
```

[jsiddle Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/gNL46/)